Flutter Firebase auth handle errors
I want to create a user account using Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword. I want the conditon thatif there is no error in the FirebaseAuthException it should create the account and then later perform a task. But if there is an error, the other task should not be performed. But in my code whether there is an error or not the second task goes ahead to execute. How can I prevent this?
My code for reating the account
signUp() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email.text, password: password.text)
          .whenComplete(() {
        upload();//
      });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == "email-already-in-use") {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.black,
          msg: widget.emailExist,
        );
      } else {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.black,
          msg: e.toString(),
        );
      }
    }
  }

I want to call the upload() method when the user account completes the creation, that is if there is no error. But in this my case even when there is an error, the upload() is called anyway. How can I rectify it?

whenComplete runs whether there's an error or not. To only run on success, use then.
